# Django mpld3 show json serializable error

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-templates, mpld3

I am trying to display a multi dimensional bar chart using mpld3 and django framework.

when I run the following code, it produces error

> Object of type 'ndarray' is not JSON serializable

at `fig_to_html()` function line

here I attached my working copy:

view.py

```
def home(request):
    get_barchart = barchart()

    return render(request,"home.html",{
        "barchart":get_barchart
    }
)

def barchart():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.scatter([1, 10], [5, 9])
    html_graph = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)

    return html_graph
```

html template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chart Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>Chart Example</h3>
        <div>
            {{ barchart|safe }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: yes i attached my code